# I need a service for generation sentence included a set of words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-generation

I need to generate random but lexically correct sentences with my words included. The sentence doesn't have to consist entirely of my words. But the more of them the better.

I have already searched through a lot of resources related to machine learning, but everywhere they write about generating RANDOM texts. I can't influence the result in any way by specifying the presence of at least a couple of my words as a condition.

Perhaps someone on this resource knows about repositories with similar libraries or APIs where I can get something like this?

Answer (score 0):

After a week of searching, I can say that there is no ready-to-use library or service for this.

If you data scientist, you may found this problem interesting for a creation your own startup, i think.